# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION,

Tags: php

what is wrong with this error i dont get it... it actualy works when i m connected to localhost but when i run it on a free domain i get this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/a7812073/public_html/core/init.php on line 21** and i inserted the right info for the mysql server

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS ['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'lr'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';

});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));
    if($hashCheck->count()) {
        $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
        $user->login();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using in production? I bet it is older than the local version you have.

Comment: Sounds like you have PHP < 5.3. Anonymous functions like that passed to `spl_autoload_register()` are 5.3+

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski is correct. Should put it in an answer. Check your version and upgrade if you want to use anonymous functions.

Comment: on the website it says   5.2.*

Comment: @lenart95 I'd recommend getting a better (non-free) host. PHP 5.2 is way out of date, and hasn't been supported with security patches for years.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski do you know any free or are there only non-free ?

Comment: @lenart95 I'm not really in the market for hosts so I can't advise. I do hear over and over again here on SO that you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to register an anonymous function using `spl_autoload_register()`, but as you told that you are using PHP5.2 on your web server.

Unfortunately PHP < 5.3 does not support anonymous functions. You need to write a "regular" function:

```
function my_autoload($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
```

This will work on PHP >= 5.3 as well.

Comment: is it better if i look for a new domain that uses new php version cuz after i fixed this error i get new one and so on..

Comment: Needless to say: Yes! :) PHP 5.2 is quiet old. Before you change your hosting contract, you might ask them if they already support php > 5.2. Mostly they do, but it's up to you to upgrade (in order to avoid breaking anything)